# pandas plot : fixing a color by value

Tags: python, pandas

Having a df :

```
import random
import pandas as pd
def get_row():
    row = {"date" : random.choice(range(10)), "status" : random.choice(["won", "lost", "onoing"]), "id" : random.choice(range(10))}
    return row
df = pd.DataFrame([get_row() for i in range(100)])
tab  = df.pivot_table(index="date", columns="status", values="id", aggfunc="count")
tab
```

which gives me : 
[image]

I can try to plot :

```
tab.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

How can I fix a color for each column ? 
I would like "lost" to be red, "won" to be green, "ongoing" to be blue.

Well, I found the answer :

```
gcolors = {'lost': 'red', 'onoing': 'blue', 'won': 'green'}
tab.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=[gcolors[group] for group in tab])
```

gives : 
[image]

Comment: Seems like you can delete this question since you self answering it :-)

Comment: Don't delete the question. It is a good one. The answer is good too. Post the answer yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I said, while asking the question, I found the answer :

```
gcolors = {'lost': 'red', 'onoing': 'blue', 'won': 'green'}
tab.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=[gcolors[group] for group in tab])
```